# DayPickerInput limit date selection

Tags: reactjs

I am using `DayPickerInput` in my react application. I know how to use before and after to limit the date selection but those options doesn't work together (for me). However individually they do work well and restrict date selection.

```
<DayPickerInput                                                                                             
   dayPickerProps={{                                                                                                   
     disabledDays: {
       before: today,                                                                                             
       after: afterDate                                                                                         
     }
   }}
 />
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable days by following way with your `DayPickerInput`:

```
dayPickerProps={{
   disabledDays: [
     { before: moment().subtract(1, 'months').toDate() },
     { after: moment().toDate() },
   ]
}}
```